# Derivative of modulus operator

Tags: calculus, modular-arithmetic

What is the derivative of $x \bmod  b$ with respect to x?

I understand that it would be a piecewise function but I couldn't figure out a clean way of representing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x$ is divisible by $b$ then the function $x\ \mathrm{ mod }\ b$ is discontinuous at $x$ and there is no deriviative.

Otherwise, let $x$ divided by $b$ be $q$ with the reminder $r$, so

$$r = x\ \mathrm{ mod }\ b, \qquad x=b\cdot q + r$$

You can see that in a neighborhood of $x$ that $q$ is constant, so we have

$$r=x-b\cdot q$$

where $b\cdot q$ is constant. Thus, the derivative is just $1$.

To summarize, the derivative is $1$ except where $x$ is an integral multiple of $b$, then the derivative is undefined. I suppose you could call this a piecewise-continuous or piecewise-linear function.

---

Here's another way to look at it. Another way to define your function is

$$x\ \mathrm{mod}\ b = x - b \cdot \mathrm{int}\left(\frac xb\right)$$

If you know the graph of the $\mathrm{int}$ function you know that it is piecewise constant: between integer values of $u$, $\mathrm{int}(u)$ is a horizontal line. Thus its derivative at integer values of $u$ is undefined and elsewhere it is zero. Now take the derivative of that expression--the $x$ term leaves a derivative of $1$ and the rest, by the chain rule, has an undefined derivative when $\frac xb$ is an integer and zero otherwise. That leads to the same conclusion as above.

A graph always helps these questions. Here is a graph from the TI-Nspire CX graphing calculator, which has a $\mathrm{mod}$ function built in. In this example I used $b=\pi$.

[image]

You can see the slope of the graph is $1$ everywhere except where the graph breaks, which is at multiples of pi.

Comment: How are you defining divisibility and  $x\bmod b$ for *reals*?

Comment: @BillDubuque: I thought it was clear, but to state it differently--if $b\ne 0$, we can define it as $r=b\cdot \mathrm{frac} \left(\frac xb \right)$ where that means the fractional part. We then have $q=\mathrm{int}\left(\frac xb\right)$.

Comment: @artiespeedy: In an interval, as long as $x$ stays away from integral multiples of $b$, $q$ remains constant thus so does $b\cdot q$. Now that I have more time, I'll include a graph in my answer.